# How to checking remote machine is active or not using tool?

Tags: java, memcached, keep-alive

1)Initially I have 5 servers.I am passing one by one server Ip through java code.
2)If machine is InActive then send an email to admin.
3)I need a tool for remote machine is up or down (up means active and down inActive).

Plz help me

Thanks in advance
Sekhar

Comment: How about [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/)? [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask though

Comment: Check also [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) and [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) out.

Comment: Maybe you could simply use `ping`?

Comment: As Smutje says you can use ping, if you need to use Java here how to implement it (http://www.coderanch.com/t/570467/sockets/java/Ping-IP-address-Java)